# Can't split array in C program

Tags: c, arrays, memcpy

I am trying to split my 32 bit char array in 2 16 bit array but it gives weird output of more than 16 bit. Any help over this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "hexb.h"
#include "flr.h"


int main()
{   int i,j,k;  
    char inbit[20];
    char fdata[31],coeff[15],signb[15];
    printf("Enter X(n) data file with extension: ");
    scanf("%s",inbit);
    //strcpy(inbit,flr);
    printf(" Data in file :%s\n", flr(inbit));
    //printf(" Hex conversion : %s\n", hexc(flr(inbit)));
    strcpy(fdata,"11001101001011011001000101001000");
    printf(" Hex conversion : %s\n", fdata);
    memcpy(signb, fdata, 16);
    memcpy(coeff, fdata +16, 16);
    //signb[15] = fdata[15];
    //coeff[15] = fdata[31];
    printf(" part1  signbit : %s\n", signb);
    printf(" part2 valuebit : %s\n", coeff); return (0);}
```

surprisingly output is more than 16 bit

```
Enter X(n) data file with extension: coeff.in
Data in file :CD2D9148
 Hex conversion : 11001101001011011001000101001000
 part1  signbit : 1100110100101101coeff.in
 part2 valuebit : 10010001010010001100110100101101coeff.in
```

Comment: thanks olaf , adding \0 solve my problem.

Comment: Rolled back to previous version. Do not change your question after you got answers such as to make the answers useless or out-of-context! Instead, add some text, if you still have an issue. If you encounter a different problem, you should ask a new question. Please note that stack overflow is no discussion site or forum, but a Q&A site. It also requires an enquirer to do some research on his own (it is also no tutorial site).

Comment: regarding this line: `scanf("%s",inbit);`  1) always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.  2) the `%s` format/conversion specifier will allow the user to enter more than 19 characters, thereby overflowing the input buffer `inbit` resulting in undefined behaviour, which can lead to a seg fault event.  suggest: `scanf("%19s",inbit);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, this line

```
strcpy(fdata,"11001101001011011001000101001000");
```

results in buffer overflow because `fdata` (array size 31) is smaller than your source string.

Similarly

```
memcpy(signb, fdata, 16);
memcpy(coeff, fdata +16, 16);
```

are using destination buffers that are too small to receive the amount of daya that you are trying to copy to them - `signb` and `coeff` are arrays of size 15 but you are trying to copy 16 bytes into them. You cannot read or write beyond an arrays bounds without invoking undefined behaviour.

Once you have invoked undefined behaviour there is little point in trying to interpret the results you are getting. You need to resize your arrays accordingly so that they are large enough for your requirements - this includes allowing for the terminating null characters required in order to use them as strings.

Comment: can you help with this new issue ?

Comment: @VirbhadraRathod Rather than edit a question that already has answers, it is better to ask a **new** question with the new problem. Editing the question after answers are posted runs the risk that the answers are made to look meaningless because you have corrected the issues in your code sample.

Comment: @mathematician1975: You should have rolled back the edit (I did now). This edit was clearly a violation of the rules.

Comment: This answer does not cover all issues. The smaller arrays have to be terminated.

Comment: @Olaf OP is a fairly new user - I thought it best to inform that it is not a good idea to edit rather than just roll back. As for your second point, I do clearly state that all arrays need to be resized and null terminated.

Comment: User is here for ca. 4 Months (just one less than I am actually). I would not call him a "new user". The added part was not that much, so he can add again (it might be a good lesson), but the modifications were more grave. I also left a comment that and why I rolled back. This should give enough info. For the terminator: Ok, I overlooked the part after _undefined behaviour_ (I normally do not inspect further after UB;-).

Comment: @Olaf Fair enough - I suppose all that matters is that the edit point was made to OP

Answer (score 2):

The arrays are one char too small for the desired contents already (You have to specify the number of elements, not the number of the last valid index). Additionally you forgot about the NUL-terminator required for C strings. So, first enlarge the arrays by two entries:

```
char fdata[33],coeff[17],signb[17];
```

Then you have to append `'\0'` to the two smaller arrays after the `memcpy`s, because they do not know about.

This because the `printf`s require valid strings.

Note that reading a string with `scanf` is unsafe, as user-input is not limited. This results in *undefined behaviour* (variant "buffer overflow", the classic fault). Either read the string with `fgets` (do not use `gets` for the same reason), or limit the length in `scanf` (I'll leave finding out the correct format string syntax to you).

Answer (score -1):

here is solution

```
char fdata[33],coeff[17],signb[17];
printf("Enter X(n) data file with extension: ");
scanf("%s",inbit);
//strcpy(inbit,flr);
printf(" Data in file :%s\n", flr(inbit));
//printf(" Hex conversion : %s\n", hexc(flr(inbit)));
strcpy(fdata,"11001101001011011001000101001000");
printf(" Hex conversion : %s\n", fdata);
memcpy(signb, fdata, 16);
memcpy(coeff, fdata +16, 16);
signb[16] = '\0';
coeff[16] = '\0';
```

Comment: It is not. You still forgot some. Read my answer.